# mongodb: query for free time slots in calendar model

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a calendar model with following schema ( to store the vechicle status in adjacent time slots)

```
  const calendarSchema = new Schema( {
      vehicleId: String,
      startTime: Date,
      endTime: Date,
      availability: {type:String, enum: [ 'Available', 'Booked', 'Partially_Available']
})
```

Now I would like to search for vehicles that are either `Available` or `Partially_Available` between `2021-01-01T12:00:00` to `2021-01-01T15:00:00`

For vehicleId:123 I have following documents in collection:

```
{
   vehicleId:123,
   startTime: 2021-01-01T12:00:00,
   endTime: 2021-01-01T13:00:00
   availability: 'Available'
},

{
   vehicleId:123,
   startTime: 2021-01-01T13:00:00,
   endTime: 2021-01-01T14:00:00
   availability: 'Partially_Available'
}
{
   vehicleId:123,
   startTime: 2021-01-01T14:00:00,
   endTime: 2021-01-01T15:00:00
   availability: 'Available'
}
```

Now How do I write query such that I get  `vehicleId`s which is either `Available` or `Paritally_Available`  between `2021-01-01T12:00:00` to `2021-01-01T15:00:00`

That means if any vehicle has `Booked` status for any time slots between those two interval it should not appear in the result.  For above case `vehicleId:123` should appear in result. If any one of the entries above had status `Booked`, `vehicleId:123` should not appear in result.

Thank you in advance for any suggestion. I have been scratching my head for last few days to find solution but couldn't find it yet.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
db.collection.find({
  availability: {
    $in: [ "Available", "Partially_Available" ]
  },
  startTime: {
    $gte: ISODate("2021-01-01T12:00:00.000Z")
  },
  endTime: {
    $lte: ISODate("2021-01-01T15:00:00.000Z")
  }
})
```

you can test it here [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/fUkQNqi6eb5)